# how to do UItextfield should allow only value between Range

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitextfield, nscharacterset

My Problem is i have to do Like User can enter values in Range ... My range is coming from json

here's my code whatever i tried ... here a,b is my start range and b is end range user can enter values better this range not out of range

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  if (textField)
  {
    NSData *data = [((MDCFlowDetails *)_flow).flow_data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *a = [json objectForKey:@"startrange"];
    NSString *b = [json objectForKey:@"endrange"];
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:nil];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
    if (numberOfMatches == 0)
        return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly are "startRange" and "endRange"? Are these words? Numbers? Indexes of coffee machines? Those variables are never used in the code. All I see is a regular expression (that I don't understand). You have to add more information.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch startRange and endRange are Numbers

Comment: so your range is max and min newString length?

Comment: @Mateusz yes min and max length

Comment: Sorry for ask question but Is there any reason for use regex for this type of validation ?? Why don't just take ascii of start range and end range value and do validation ?

Comment: @Jageen i have to set value from json data so i can't use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done simply by just checking `length` of textfield.

Put a condition on low and high end of range when user enter text in textfield.

See below code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField)
    {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        NSData *data = [((MDCFlowDetails *)_flow).flow_data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSInteger a = [[json objectForKey:@"startrange"] integerValue];
        NSInteger b = [[json objectForKey:@"endrange"] integerValue];

        if (newString.length > a && newString.length > b) {
            // Check both range are satisfied.
            return NO;
        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If some one use a ios keyboard to write something and 'a' will be greater then 0 this will never work, you should remove this lines `if(newString.length < a) {return NO;}` and check it later.

Comment: @Mateusz It's now depends on OP's requirement. We can also merge two condition but its not clear though how strict range validation is there. How ever if you think any improvement required than feel free to modify it.

Comment: @Mateusz I have put a validation while user try to remove characters below from the range. But still you see it can never remove after below that range.

Comment: the point is that when this method returns `NO` the text field will not change. If for example `a` is set to 3, then even if you tap 4 times on some keyboard letter this will never change the text field because for every press 'newString.length' will be 1. But you have right: 'It's now depends on OP's requirement'

Comment: @Kampai above example not working because u specify if(newString.length < a) so it not working i want to allow values

Comment: @MayankPatel - If you want user to bound between these two range than we must have to put lower bound range condition. If you requirement is still different than let me know what exact range validation you want.

Comment: @Kampai I want suppose Condition like that user enter only 5 to 9 values in UITextfield i have to validate this

Comment: @MayankPatel- You mean text length should be between these range, right? Is so then check edited answer.